# Can a progressive marginal taxation be regressive in terms of average tax rate?

Tags: taxation, public-economics

Or does progressive marginal taxation imply that it is a progressive average taxation?

Here, I mean that if $T(Y)$ is a tax function of income, marginal tax rate would be $dT/dY$ and average tax rate would be $T(Y)/Y$.

Comment: Is it assumed that there is no per capita tax, that is $T(0) = 0$? And is it assumed that $T(Y)$ is continuous?

Comment: No none of these are assumed. It just needs to be well defined. But then we will have to talk about intervals. For example, the function $T(Y)=0$ for $0<Y<10$, and $T(Y)=Y-10, 10<Y$ is progressive in marginal tax if we view it as intervals, but constant if we consider the progressivity within the intervals.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In comments it was clarified that $T(Y) = 0$ and continuity are not assumed. In this case there are several counterexamples, a relatively simple one being
$$
T(Y) = \left\{
\begin{array}{ll} 
1 + 20\%Y & \text{if } Y \leq 5 \\
40\% Y & \text{if } Y > 5.
\end{array}
\right. 
$$
Here the taxation is progressive, but the average tax rate $T(Y)/Y$ is close to infinite near $Y = 0$ as
$$
\lim_{Y \to 0} \frac{1}{Y} + 20\% = \infty,
$$
and $T(Y)/Y$ is smaller later, e.g. $T(5)/5 = 2/5$.

As long as $T(0) > 0$ or there is a positive jump at any income level $Y$, the average tax rate may not be monotonically increasing.

(The reader may use the math of the cost functions $AC,MC$ to examine this.)

Comment: Actually, isn't this function regressive in terms of marginal tax rate, since the second derivative is negative?

Comment: Seems like you are right! Will edit later.

Comment: @Yejin I edited the answer.

Answer (score 3):

$$
\frac{\partial\frac{T(Y)}{Y}}{\partial Y}= \frac{T'(Y)}{Y} - \frac{T(Y)}{Y^2}
$$

This can only be smaller than 0 if

$$ T'(Y) < \frac{T(Y)}{Y} $$

In other words, the marginal tax rate needs to be smaller than the average tax rate. This can't happen because you start with an average tax rate of zero and a positive marginal tax rate. From then on, in a progressive scheme, the tax due increases faster than taxable income. Progressive taxation is actually characterized by the fact that the marginal tax rate exceeds the average one. [See here, p.27](https://papers.ssrn.com/sol3/papers.cfm?abstract_id=931128).

Comment: "you start with an average tax rate of zero" How so?

Comment: if your income is zero, you don't pay taxes. at some point, you will start to pay one \$ on some amount of income. So your average tax rate will be very close to zero when taxation kicks in.

Comment: Why? Suppose $T(Y) = 20\% \cdot Y$. Then the average tax rate is constantly $20\%$, is it not?

Comment: Giskard is correct that the fact that $T(0)=0$ tells us nothing about the _rate_ at 0 income (and an argument involving limits can get around the 0/0 problem for computing the average) but I think it doesn’t actually matter.  I think the rest of the argument holds anyway.